# when I use flatMap in scala show this error

Tags: scala

this is my code

```
def createList(num: Int) = {
  num to num + 10
}
Some(1).flatMap(createList)
```

after complier , it show words : error: type mismatch

I know

```
Some(1).toSeq.flatMap(createList) 
or
Some(1).flatMap(Some(createList))
```

can right

If I use this can do too:

```
def createBox(a: Int) = Box(Some(a)
Some(1).flatMap(createBox)
```

see implicit Box2Option in [documention](http://liftweb.net/api/26/api/#net.liftweb.common.Box),is this work

Box is type from liftWeb frameWork

Comment: Isn't `Some` an optional ("maybe") value? If so, why are calling a collection/sequence method on it? Or why aren't you using a collection/sequence if you need one?

Comment: Because I have a query need a paramter(which is Some(id)), the return a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Option#flatMap` [accepts](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Some@flatMap%5BB%5D%28f:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D%29:Option%5BB%5D) `A => Option[B]`, not `A => Seq[B]`.

Try this:

```
Some(1).toSeq.flatMap(createList)
```

Comment: Some(1).flatMap(Some(crateList)) also can do .

Comment: @jinglining: `Some` is subtype of `Option`. `flatMap` is method of type `Option`.

Comment: but in Idea , it tell me the flatMap from List

Comment: @jinglining: see [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Some@flatMap%5BB%5D%28f:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D%29:Option%5BB%5D). `flatMap` on `Some` is from `Option`.

Comment: Ok, I have a question : I use lifeWeb frameWork, if I write this :`val a = Box(Some(1))  Some(1).flatMap(a)`; why this can work

Comment: @jinglining: because `Box` extends `A => Option[B]`.

Comment: I find Option and Box all extends Product, it is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `createList` function should wrap its result in an Option (since you are calling `flatMap` on an Option). In alternative, you could just use `map` instead of `flatMap` and your function would just work. Actually, what do you expect as a result? An `Option` or a `Seq`?